# Getting 403/404/500 errors when trying to launch/publish an ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to learn ASP.NET and .NET/C# for work. I wasn't able to find how to make something go live...the right way. Every instruction I find forgets to speak on how to make an app live.

Taking it into my own hands, I've triend many things and I was able to publish my files online to my Godaddy hosting account (PLESK), but I kept getting 403/404/500 errors.

Eventually after a few days and trying a few things, I was able to get a basic test page up by editing web.config and as an example, adding something like:

```
  <defaultDocument enabled="true">
     <files>
        <add value="MYHOMEPAGEFILEHERE.html" />
     </files>
  </defaultDocument>
```

This worked because it's so basic and it points to basic html file, but the problem I'm having though is that I'm trying to launch a site that has razor/routes established/classes and C# stuff (no DB yet) and on my local machine, the site/app works but when I upload it, it always breaks and I get 403s, 500s etc...

I thought to myself *"maybe add default document path/value to any of the starting C# files, like I would do in a MEAN app (via app.js)"*.

But when I looked in the server, none of those files are there, I'm going to assume that all the C# files, are compiled into dll files?

If this is the case, how do I go about instructing the server to start at any particular file? Essentially, what can I do, to upload my working mini app(locally) to an online server, and it just work?

I've followed everythng I could find wether it was allowing user access, adding permissions to directories etc...

Comment: Does your hosting plan include ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC? If not, then you need to get a different plan, or even a different hosting provider. The default 'document' or better default URL on MVC is typically `/Home/Index`, which means that the **`HomeController`** class will be started and its method **`Index()`** will be executed, which then renders the page. Also see this: **https://www.godaddy.com/help/do-your-hosting-accounts-support-mvc4-and-mvc5-applications-8999**

Comment: Good question. Honestly, i dont know. i purchased godaddy hosting and thought that was it....let me call them and ask

Comment: @PeterB Generally a host doesn't need to "include MVC". It just needs to support ASP.NET. Your application will then include the MVC libraries.

Comment: Just called them and it is windows hosting and MVC is supported

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-host-your-Asp-Net-mvc-website-on-godaddy-server/

Comment: You are right: publishing an MVC project is not easy, and information out there "forgets" that step. Have you checked out Microsoft's guide? It helped me: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/